# Object-oriented programming error

Tags: python

```
class Ammo(Thing):

    # constructor here
    def __init__(self,name,weapon,quantity):
        self.name = name
        self.weapon = weapon
        self.quantity = quantity

    # definition of weapon_type here
    def weapon_type(self):
        return self.weapon
```

This is my code and when i try to retrieve the `weapon_type` as a `string` 
Here are my Inputs

```
bow = Weapon('bow', 10, 20)
arrows = Ammo('arrow', bow, 5)
print(arrows.weapon_type())   ## bow
```

I don't get `bow` instead I get `<__main__.Weapon object at 0x0211DCB0>`

Comment: What does "I can't Inputs" mean?

Comment: What problem are you having? Also, can you please provide the code for the Weapon class as well?

Comment: I hope you have defined __str__(self) inside Weapon class

Comment: Your sample doesn't show any error, and you don't tell what the problem is. What do you expect to get? What do you get instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`arrows.weapon_type()` will currently return a Weapon rather than a string. `print` *will* convert it for you, but I'm guessing  it's printing something like this:

```
<__main__.Weapon object at 0x7ffea6de6208>
```

to get it to print something more useful, you can control how it converts to string. Print calls the builtin function [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str) on its arguments, which calls the method `__str__` - in other words, if you define your Weapon class like this:

```
class Weapon:
    # other methods
    def __str__(self):
        return self.type + " weapon"
```

then `str(a_weapon)`, and by extension `print(a_weapon)` will do something more sensible.

Comment: Actually I got it simply by returning str(self.weapon)